# ¿Como obtener la cantidad de elementos que tiene un JSON con GSON en Java?

Tags: java, json, servlets, netbeans-8.2, gson

Desde el `Front-end` mando el archivo `JSON`, luego en el `Servlet`, a través de `GSON` lo transformo en un objeto:

```
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String texto = request.getReader().readLine();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    json1 = gson.fromJson(texto, Reserva.class);
```

Lo que quiero hacer es contabilizar la cantidad de elementos que tiene el archivo `JSON`. O contabilizar la cantidad de elementos que contiene el objeto Java (`json1`).

Este es el `JSON`:

```
{
  "hot": "1",
  "numN": "1",
  "tipH": "camasimple ",
  "fechl": "2018-05-24",
  "num": "1",
  "numa": "1"
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Dependerá de si es un `JSONArray` O un `JSONObject`. Lo mejor es que publiques el JSON para ver la estructura.

Comment: Hola Victor. Gracias por responder. Este es el Json. `{"hot":"1","numN":"1","tipH":"camasimple ","fechl":"2018-05-24","num":"1","numa":"1"}`

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo este ejemplo que te puede servir:

```
public void listarJson(){
        String urlstr="http://localhost:8080/JavaWebServiceServerCRUD/rest/empleados/json/listarempleados";
        try{
            URL url = new  URL(urlstr);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();     
            JsonReader rdr=Json.createReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            JsonArray results= rdr.readArray();
            Iterator<?> iterator = results.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) iterator.next();
                System.out.println("JSON-> El id es: "+jsonObject.get("id").toString().toUpperCase()+", el nombre es: "+jsonObject.get("nombre").toString().toUpperCase()+", el puesto es: "+jsonObject.get("puesto").toString().toUpperCase());
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Como puedes ver usa un iterator:

```
Iterator<?> iterator = results.iterator();
```